# Unable to inject Service into HttpInterceptor properly

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic 4, and Angular 7. I am trying to intercept HTTP requests and add a token to the header. The problem is that the `token` is always null when I try retrieving it from `AuthService`. I have adding `AuthService` to the `TokenInterceptor` constructor and also injecting `AuthService`. Neither of them work. What am I doing wrong?

AuthService.ts

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService
{

  public token: string;
  public refreshToken: string;

  constructor
  (
    private http: HttpClient,
    private storage: StorageService,
  )
  {

    this.API_URL      = constants.API_URL;
    this.OAUTH_URL    = constants.AUTH_URL;

      this.storage.getTokens().then(tokens => {
        this.token            = tokens.access_token;
        this.refreshToken     = tokens.refresh_token;
      });

  }
}
```

TokenInterceptorService

```
@Injectable()
  export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor
  {

    constructor
    (
        private auth: AuthService,
    )
    {
    }

    setHeaders(req: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
        return req.clone({
          setHeaders: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
              'Accept': 'application/json',
          }
        });
    }

    public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
    {

        console.log("token int", this.auth);    // I CAN SEE TOKEN HERE  
        console.log("token int2", this.auth.token); // TOKEN IS UNDEFINED 
        return next.handle(this.setHeaders(req, this.auth.token));
     }
}
```

Providers array in App.Module.ts

providers: [
  // .... 
  AuthService,
  APIService,
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
    multi: true,
  },
]

I have also tried injecting AuthService but it doesn't work

```
@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor
{

private auth;

constructor
(
    private injector: Interjector
)
{
  this.auth = this.injector.get(AuthService);
}

  setHeaders(req: HttpRequest<any>, token: string): HttpRequest<any> {
      return req.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        }
      });
  }

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>>
  {

      console.log("token int", this.auth); // I CAN SEE THE TOKEN HERE ALONG WITH ALL OF THE OTHER VARIABLES AND DECLERATIONS IN `AUTHSERVICE`.  
      console.log("token int2", this.auth.token); // TOKEN IS UNDEFINED 
      return next.handle(this.setHeaders(req, this.auth.token));
   }
}
```

I have also tried adding `AuthService` as a dependency for the `TokenInterceptorService`

```
providers: [
  // .... 
  AuthService,
  APIService,
  {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: TokenInterceptorService,
    multi: true,
     deps: [AuthService],
  },
  // ....
]
```

Comment: For one thing, you seem to have a cyclic dependency between the auth service (which requires HttpClient), HttpClient (which requires the interceptor) and the interceptor (which requires the auth service). But could you expand on what you mean by *"I CAN SEE TOKEN HERE "*?

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve the cyclic dependancy. if I log `this.auth` I can see all the variables in `AuthService` including `token`.

Answer (score 1):

AuthService is bad idea. Because it is the singleton so the token value can't sync, and Storage.getTokens is sync method, you also can't sure AuthService.Token is ready before you use it. And others, 1: you can't get new Token if it was updated; 2: you can't know user already logout.

So, please do it in setHeaders method is better. In my source the logic like it:

```
//TokenInterceptorService
async setHeaders(url) {
  let baseHeader = {/*default values*/};
  if (url in sign-in, register, logout, home or other public api) {
    return baseHeader;
  }
  let token = {};
  await storage.getToken().then(tokenData => {
    token = tokenData;
  };
  baseHeader.token = token;
  return baseHeader;
}
```

Comment: Sorry do what in setHeaders method?

Comment: I just added pseudo code there, hope it is helpful.